# How to revert and go the previous stage before commit

Tags: git, rebase, git-revert

I am new at version control system (git). I did a mistake and when I realize it happen its too late. what I did

```
(1) commit current work 
(2) git pull --rebase origin master
```

Then I go to a previous commit using

```
(3) git checkout 858223adcac47288c44c4c07fbc3938773d778b8
```

Now I need to go the previous stage(1) before committed. And I really don't know how to go there. **That's mean I want to go my master and undo the rebase**. 

I heartily thank if anyone tell me how to do this.

Comment: maybe `git checkout master` do the first job but it said Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout. But I don't care for them. how to get rid of them?

Comment: Then you can do `git stash save . ` and `git checkout master`

Answer (score 1):

`git` saves history of `refs` (read `branches`) mostly for this kind of scenarios when you want a commit that is no longer reachable from any of the current `refs`.

Unless enough time passed or you explicitly made `reflog` entries expire and garbage collect, the history is available by issuing `git reflog <branch>` outputting changes to branch to in form of `<sha> <action description leading to changing value of branch>` starting with most recent one.

Find the one you want to get back to (probably one that was prior to the commit you mentioned), examining:

`git reflog master`

Check it out to double check the contents:

`git checkout <sha>`

Move to master and `reset` master to that commit (caution that `hard reset` is potentially dangerous/troublesome if used incorrectly):

`git checkout master`

`git reset --hard <sha>`

---

Some notes:

How `git-rebase` works. This will help to understand how `no longer reachable` can arise during `rebase`  https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

It's also possible to create another commit on top of `rebased` commit that effectively undoes the pulled part, but that's less practical and noted for completeness only.

Comment: I forgot about (3), seems like, you already know which commit you want to reset to, if so, that's the sha I was suggesting to find from `reflog`.

Comment: @rkta I'm not fully sure if the commit in (3) is what OP wants to revert to, I'll wait for disambiguation from OP on that, meanwhile the answer provides solution for general case.

Comment: @NajmunNahar Does this answer your question, and can you clarify the previous point (hash in (3)), please?